# setting and storing time in an array and attach to datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am going nuts over JavaScript and time. I have 2 things going on. First is a date picker using JqueryUI. It works as coded and alerts the selected date. On this tho I need to not allow it to selected a past date.

Second is I have created an array of times. The times need 15 minutes added to the next index item. I have created that just fine with a few problems. I set the hours to start at 8. Works great but it grabs the current minutes. I have tried to set the minutes to 0 and 1 and -1 and many others. However this does not work. The other issue is while it adds 15 minutes the current minutes once it passes the hour of 8 it repeats. Meaning it adds another 8 hour instead of turning over to 9.

Finally I need the array to be set to the date selected on the date picker. So if say someone selects October 1 2015 the array contains times in 15 minute intervals for October 1 2015 starting at 8.

I created a JsFiddle for this so that I could test many ways to make this work. I have not been able to do so yet. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Here is the js

```
var Times = [];
var d = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++)
{
    Times.push( d );
    d = new Date( d.setHours(8) + 15*60*1000 );  // 15 minutes in milliseconds
}


$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'MM, dd, yy', 
    onSelect: function(dateText) 
    { 
        var selectedDate = dateText;
        alert(selectedDate);
    }
});


alert(Times);
```

JsFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/andy77888/2k93x7g1/#base

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent past dates from being selected:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

Comment: Thank you. That takes care of one part. I am still very lost on the other.